# Reuse a Client TCP Socket for Multiple HTTP Connections

Tags: c, http, asynchronous, tcp, posix

Greetings all.

I am making a ANSI C multi-threaded www-crawler (HTTP 1.1 compatible) on Linux 2.6.29-3.ydl61.3 and fairly progressed well. I have '000 of domains in a MySQL database to collect pages from. I can open any/all the domains in the crawler in keep-alive mode, as desired. I use POSIX threading and there are no contentions or data races whatsoever.

While the target servers seem ready to allow me to issue multiple concurrent or sequential requests for pages on each server socket (since each server returns 'Connection: Keep-Alive' as expected), I cannot actually do so... I can only fetch one page per socket connection... i.e. I can write a typical HTTP GET request to the socket via a file-descriptor and read down the response. Then immediately after that, I can only write to the fd BUT NOT read anymore!  So while I have multiple (some into hundreds) urls per domain... it seems that I have to keep recreating socket connections to the same servers for each write/read (extremely memory wasteful and slow) rather than create only one client TCP connection and keep reusing the fd/socket until am done with the domain.

See below a partial output of 'netstat --inet -a' (note that as undesired I have multiple local socket connections to the same domain - these are not concurrent per domain):

tcp        0      0 gcell1:38614             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell1:34678             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34768             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:56085             www.hihostels.com:http      CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34661             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34785             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46660             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34697             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:37510             www.kenic.or.ke:http        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:37516             www.kenic.or.ke:http        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34710             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34711             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46677             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:56513             www.kenic.or.ke:http        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:57560             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46634             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46607             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46666             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:37526             www.kenic.or.ke:http        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:46673             67.225.194.54:http          CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34736             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:57557             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:56395             www.kenic.or.ke:http        CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34714             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34669             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:34767             x2web02.myhosting.com:http  CLOSE_WAIT
tcp        0      0 gcell11:43381             ip-72-167-251-99.ip.se:http CLOSE_WAIT

The client socket is created as below (partial code only)

```
if((http_socket_fd = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP))!=SKMG_FAILURE) //typical
...
fcntl(http_socket_fd,SOCK_NONBLOCK); //set to non-block
...
setsockopt(http_socket_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, &optval, optlen); //local TCP keep-alive used
...
while(connect(http_socket_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&http_name, sizeof (struct sockaddr_in)) == (-1))
...
return http_socket_fd;
```

After this I just use write/read on the fd. And it works perfectly BUT for ONLY one round trip.

1) How can I reuse `http_socket_fd` for each HTTP GET write/read per domain without needing to create a new local TCP socket for each url?? Merely passing `http_socket_fd` to every page fetch call per domain is exactly what has failed to work. [CRITICAL]

2) How can I make asynchronous requests to these servers on this one thread per socket per domain paradigm? I run 4 concurrent threads (my server is dual-threaded), i.e. 4 different concurrent domain fetches. [NON-CRITICAL]

Comment: Could you add an example request/response?

Comment: Somebody pls help!!! Why can't I reuse the http client socket, since I don't call close(http_socket_fd)???? I don't want to keep recreating a new client connection socket to the same host for successive requests. Is it not possible in C to reuse an open client socket (which already has HTTP keep-alive enabled) for successive read/writes? It seems possible with Java http://www.mail-archive.com/httpclient-dev@jakarta.apache.org/msg04687.html

Answer (score -1):

The usual practice is to create one client socket per connection. It is also a bad idea to share sockets among threads.

Instead of writing your own HTTP client, have you ever considered using a library like [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) that provide many advanced features? The libcurl site has [a sample program](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/multithread.html) that downloads content using multiple threads. Also have a look at [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/), a high-performance messaging framework. A ZeroMQ socket could be used to connect to multiple servers and efficiently download data. (See [The Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall)).

Comment: Vijay, thanks for prompt response and suggestions to use a 3rd party library. Correction, I don't share sockets across threads at all! I clearly said so in ... "one thread per socket per domain paradigm"... Each threads of my 4 threads in a pool only deals with one socket, and in turn each socket connects to one domain only. My question has to do with keeping this exact approach for all successive connections to each domain. About 3rdp library, it's one of those rare occasions I'd rather not deal with a black box and need absolute control of the code for a specific reason.

Comment: I had to give this a negative point as this was still the top result for this question. I agree that people usually shouldn't create a new http server that doesn't mean it's not something you should do if you want to learn. Your answer was wrong even at the time persistent connections where default for HTTP 1.1.